# CMake Install Linking shared libraries

Tags: cmake

I have an executable that depends on two shared libraries. I put install commands in all there CMakeLists.txt as show bellow. `make install` command installs it correctly. but it gets

> error while loading shared libraries:

executable CMakeLists.txt

```
. . .
ADD_EXECUTABLE(exename ${PPOV_SOURCES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exename LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} -lutil)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exename LINK_PUBLIC exename-acceptor)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(exename LINK_PUBLIC exename-rest)

add_subdirectory(acceptor)
add_subdirectory(rest)

INSTALL(TARGETS exename DESTINATION bin)
```

exename-acceptor/CMakeLists.txt

```
ADD_LIBRARY(exename-acceptor SHARED ${ACCEPTOR_SOURCES})
INSTALL(TARGETS exename-acceptor LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

exename-rest/CMakeLists.txt

```
ADD_LIBRARY(exename-rest SHARED ${REST_SOURCES})
INSTALL(TARGETS exename-rest LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

What is the correct way of witting INSTALL commands ? is it okay to always rely on the default destination paths ? or should I specify a different installation path ? is it a good practice to set RPATH ?

Comment: What is your platform ? Also, where do the binaries and libraries actually get installed ?

Comment: I am on fedora. binaries are currently being installed in /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib by default

Comment: Could you please check that the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory (if it exists on fedora) actually contains a file that references /usr/local/lib ? The shared library loader needs to know where the libraries are located.

Comment: that directory contains 6 other conf files. none of them refers to `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: then, try to add it somewhere, some platforms (like the Ubuntu 15.04 I'm using) seem to include it by default, but some others don't.

Comment: appeneded `/usr/local/lib` on `/etc/ld.so.conf`. Still same error

Comment: ah, and don't forget to run `sudo ldconfig` to refresh the library cache.

Comment: thanks that worked. But is it a standard practice to install on default locations ?

Comment: It depends whether you intend your library to be used by third-party programs. Standard path is better as to invoke the principle of least surprise, but if your library is private to your application, using RPATH is ok.